# Http Request in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I was trying to convert the following snippet in nodejs to typescript: [How do I make Http Request in Nodejs](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/)

Here is my TypeScript code:

```
import * as http from 'http';

export class HttpRequest{
url: string;
private path: string;
private host: string;
private args: Array<Array<string>>;

constructor(url: string, args?: string){
    this.url = url;
    this.processUrl(this.url);
    if(!!args){
        this.processArgs(args);
    }
    this.args = [];
}
private processUrl(url: string): void {
    let tld: number = url.lastIndexOf('.')
    let sep: number = url.indexOf('/', tld);
    this.host = url.slice(0, sep);
    this.path = url.slice(sep+1);
}
private processArgs(args: string): void {
    let sep: number = args.indexOf('&');
    if(sep < 0){
        return ;
    }
    let argpair: string = args.slice(0, sep);
    let apsep: number = argpair.indexOf('=');
    let k: string = argpair.slice(0, apsep);
    let v: string = argpair.slice(apsep+1);
    this.args.push([k,v]);
    this.processArgs(args.slice(sep+1));
}
private preparePath(): string {
    let path: string = `?`;
    this.args.forEach((arg: Array<string>, i: number): void => {
        let k: string = arg[0];
        let v: string = arg[1];
        path += k + '=' + v;
        if(i == this.args.length-1){
            return ;
        }
        path += '&';
    });
    return path;
}
public addArg(key: string, value: string): void {
    try{
        this.args.push([key,value]);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
public addArgs(args: Array<Array<string>>): void {
    args.forEach((arg: Array<string>): void => {
        this.args.push(arg);
    });
}
public get(cb: (res: any) => any): void {
    let opts = {
        'host': this.host,
        'path': `/${this.path}/${this.preparePath()}`
    };
    http.request(opts, (r: http.IncomingMessage): void => {
        let data = '';
        r.on('data', (chunk: string): void => {
            console.log('Got chunk: ' + chunk);
            data += chunk;
        });
        r.on('end', (): void =>{
            console.log('Response has ended');
            console.log(data);
            cb(data);
        });
        r.on('error', (err): void => {
            console.log('Following error occured during request:\n');
            console.log(err);
        })
    }).end();
}
public test(): void {
    console.log(this.preparePath());
    console.log(`/${this.path}/${this.preparePath()}`);
}
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
// Test httpRequest

import { HttpRequest } from './httpRequest';

const request = new HttpRequest('www.random.org/integers');
request.addArg('num', '1');
request.addArg('min', '1');
request.addArg('max', '50');
request.addArg('col', '1');
request.addArg('base', '10');
request.addArg('format', 'plain');
request.addArg('rnd', 'new');
request.test();
request.get((res: string): void => {
    console.log('Response received: ' + res);
});
```

If this works correctly (I checked the link on Firefox and, it returns a plain text random number) I should get a number as a plain text. However, when I `console.log()` response, I get nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You probably needed at least `http://` in front of your url

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though `request-promise-native` probably works just fine, [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) is a way better alternative for use in TypeScript. It comes with its own type definitions and is overall less dependent on other packages. Using it's API is quite like the answer provided by Adrian, however there are a few subtle differences.

```
const url: string = 'your-url.example';

try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
} catch (exception) {
    process.stderr.write(`ERROR received from ${url}: ${exception}\n`);
}
```

Obviously you can leave out the try/catch statement if you want the exception to be handled by the client.

Comment: I agree with you on that. I have worked with axios and I have been using it comfortably for many projects since this question. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 45):

I would suggest using https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github');
const data = await response.json();

console.log(data);
```

For POST request:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const response = await fetch('https://bin.org/post', {method: 'POST', body: 'a=1'});
const data = await response.json();

console.log(data);
```

Comment: `error TS1308: 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.`

Comment: @xged that's true, to use async/await, you have to wrap the code in an async function. Otherwide you have to write e.g.
request.get(options).then((result: string) => console.log(result));
Adrian: it works, when I prepend uri with https. There are no type defs available, are they?

Comment: However for sending HTTP requests I think axios is a way better alternative...

Comment: As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated.

Comment: library is already deprecated by creator: _As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated. No new changes are expected to land. In fact, none have landed for some time. This package is also deprecated because it depends on request._

Comment: fetch and https.request handle responses differently. Fetch will follow redirects and https.request will not. If you need to check for a 301 status code, fetch will return 200 for those requests.

Answer (score -20):

Try this :

```
var request = require('request');
request('www.random.org/integers', function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    cb(response.statusCode);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Shubham I am trying to get solution in typescript not vanilla js

Comment: This solution is of typescript or u can visit at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms

Comment: @Shubham I am aware that the request module has a typings file for it. I was not looking to use request. I am trying to write something similar to request using only standard node modules. So, this does not help me.

Comment: Not sure why the solution using only request got buried while the solution using request AND request-promise-native got praised... anyway, request is deprecated now

Comment: The OP's question was about using an HTTP client in Typescript. Your solution is for plain JavaScript.