# Typescript include modules in browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, browserify

I am just getting started with TypeScript (and front end development in general) coming from a c# background so sorry if this is a really basic question, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong...

What I'm trying to do for now is create a really basic program to retrieve some sample data from a url in JSON format, parse to TS classes, and display it on the page.

In order to get the json response I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748476/http-request-in-typescript) that recommends using a node package.  I got it installed and it seems to be ok (at least TS doesn't give me any errors).

I also figured out that I need to compile (not sure if that's the right term?) with Browserify to make it browser compatible since it's using a node module.  I did that but now when I try to run in a browser it's telling me my method is not defined.

```
export class Keynote {
KeyValue: string;
Description: string;
Parent: string;
}
```

Retrieval class is:

```
import {Keynote} from "./Keynote";
import * as request from "request-promise-native";

function GetKeynotes(): Array<Keynote> {
    const baseUrl = 'https://revolutiondesign.biz/Sandbox/TypeScript/KeynoteProvider.php';
    var options = {uri: baseUrl};

    const result = JSON.parse(request.get(options));
    return result;
}
```

and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Keynotes Testing</title>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        function Retrieve() {
            var notes = GetKeynotes();
            document.getElementById('container').innerText = JSON.stringify(notes);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <button content="Get some notes" onclick="Retrieve()">Get some notes</button>
</div>
<div id="container">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Browserify is really long so I didn't want to copy here but you can see it at https://revolutiondesign.biz/Sandbox/TypeScript/KeynoteDisplay.html in the source if you want.

When I click the button I get this error in the browser:

```
KeynoteDisplay.html:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: GetKeynotes is not defined
    at Retrieve (KeynoteDisplay.html:9)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (KeynoteDisplay.html:16)
Retrieve @ KeynoteDisplay.html:9
onclick @ KeynoteDisplay.html:16
```

GetKeynotes is defined in my typescript, and on the 5th line of bundle.js I see a function with that name... Why is it undefined?

**UPDATE**

Ok I have played with jspm and SystemJs but I still don't have something right.  I referenced the module with jspm and did a bundle to build.js and uploaded the whole thing just to make sure everything is there.  Here are the tags in my html for scripts:

```
<script src="../../jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="../../config.js"></script>
<script src="build.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import("Sandbox/TypeScript/build.js")
    function Retrieve() {
        System.import("Sandbox/TypeScript/build.js")
        var notes = GetKeynotes();
        document.getElementById('container').innerText = JSON.stringify(notes);
    }
</script>
```

When I press the button I can debug in my function, but it still gives the error, 'GetKeynotes is not defined' just like before...  Again I can see a function with that name in the build.js file so I don't understand why it's not finding it.

I also tried System.import("Sandbox/TypeScript/KeynoteRetrieval.js") but it gives the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) Node tls module not supported in browsers.
    Error loading https://revolutiondesign.biz/Sandbox/TypeScript/KeynoteRetrieval.js
```

Comment: if you are going to use modules in your code you will need to use a module loader to load them as well. Look up SystemJs.

Comment: Ok I thought Browserify was a module loader, no?  Do I need both SystemJs and Browserify?  Also if there is a better way to get the url result without modules I'm open to that option for now too...